# Differences and similarities between .ttf and .ttc fonts

Tags: fonts, file-format

What is the difference between `.ttf` and `.ttc` files? I also appreciate the images to understand better. Thank you very much to everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TTF is a **TrueType Font**, while TTC is **TrueType Collection**.
TTC is the collection of several TTF compositing files.

Answer (score 8):

`ttc` stands for "TrueType Collection" and is a collection of multiple true type fonts (ttf) in one file

Answer (score -2):

Also, Windows doesn't know what to do with .TTC files, so if you are compiling fonts to include with a document, keep that in mind.

Comment: That is incorrect. Cambria.ttc, for example, is a standard font supplied with Windows and used in default Microsoft Word templates. It contains the two fonts "Cambria Regular" and "Cambria Math".